# Let $\textbf{x}$ be some constant fixed vector, and $\textbf{y}$ a uniformly distributed vector, what is the distribution of the inner product?

Tags: conditional-probability, random-vector

Suppose that $\textbf{x}$ is fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\textbf{y}$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is sampled according to a uniform distribution. Conditional on $\textbf{x}$ being fixed, what is the distribution of the conditional probability $\Pr(\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle | \textbf{x})$ ?

I know that if $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ are both random vectors sampled uniformly, the distribution of $\Pr(\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle)$ approaches the normal distribution ... But I could not look up any result on $\Pr(\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle | \textbf{x})$. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's the same? A pair of randomly-sampled vectors have the same relationship as a fixed vector and a randomly sampled vector, they only differ by a rotation, which doesn't effect the computed probability.

Comment: Okay, so that means that $\Pr(\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{y} \rangle | \textbf{x})$ is also normal ?

Comment: y is in no way conditioned on x, so the conditional probability is the same as the nonconditional one, so yeah. Although I'd still recommend waiting for someone who's more confident. (I meant to leave my original response as a comment, oops)

Comment: okay thanks still helpful though